# Wordpress action hooks priority

Tags: wordpress, hook

I try to hook the action with

```
add_action('lost_password', 'new_lost_password', 1);
```

but default action executes earlier than mine one.
How can I make priority of my action higher than default?

Comment: what happens if you change the priority, 1 in this case, to a .5 or 0?

Comment: 0 and even -100 doesn't work too

Comment: What you are trying to do? the hook does not allow you to replace the lost password page, but it's called before outputting it. If you exit in the function, you may succedd in completely replacing the page

Comment: in my hook it is wp_die method, which must make the function to exit

Comment: i'm trying to show wp_die message if posted user_name is super admin. but hook works only if user_name is not exist. else it redirects me to confirm_email page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decision is to hook 'retrieve_password' action.